# TYPO3 Breadcrumb Menu / first level no link

Tags: typo3

I´ve try to get a breadcrumb menu running. It work, but level 1 doesn´t get an link.
Output looks like that. I´ve marked the line, where the links is missing:

```
<nav>
<ol itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a href="">  !!!! should be / or https://url.tld
        <span itemprop="name">Home</span></a>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a itemprop="item" href="https://domain.tld/url">
        <span itemprop="name">Testtest</span></a>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
    </li>
</ol>
</nav>
```

Missing link on position 1 leads to errors in the google search console.
If no proper solution is available, I would hardcode level 1, but not a nice...

1.) My typoscript looks like that:

```
        50 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        50 {
            special = rootline
            includeNotInMenu = 1
            as = menuBreadcrumb
        }
```

2.) And my Fluid template:

```
 <f:if condition="{menuBreadcrumb}">
        <nav>
            <ol itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
                <f:for each="{menuBreadcrumb}" as="item" iteration="iterator">
                    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
                        <a itemprop="item" href="<f:uri.typolink parameter="{item.link}" absolute="1"/>">
                        <span itemprop="name">{item.title}</span></a>
                        <meta itemprop="position" content="{iterator.cycle}" />
                    </li>
                </f:for>
            </ol>
        </nav>
</f:if>
```

Any Ideads?
Thanks!
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is, that you do not use inline notation for the typolink viewhelper.

The easiest way to achive what you want, is to just add the `item.link` to the href parameter like this:

`<a itemprop="item" href="{item.link}">`

This should do the job. But you will not get absolute links then.

If you really need absolute links, then it's a little tricky because the Link to `/` will always generate a link to the current page.

To avoid this you could adjust your TS to:

```
50 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
50 {
    special = rootline
    begin = 2
    includeNotInMenu = 1
    as = menuBreadcrumb
}
```

This will drop the first menu item. And then you could use this menu template:

```
<f:if condition="{menuBreadcrumb}">
  <nav>
    <ol itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
      <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a itemprop="item" href="https://url.tld">
          <span itemprop="name">Home</span></a>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="0" />
      </li>
      <f:for each="{menuBreadcrumb}" as="item" iteration="iterator">
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
          <a itemprop="item" href="{f:uri.typolink(parameter: item.link, absolute: 1)}">
          <span itemprop="name">{item.title}</span></a>
          <meta itemprop="position" content="{iterator.cycle}" />
        </li>
      </f:for>
    </ol>
  </nav>
</f:if>
```

But if you do not really need absolute Links, then i would prefer the first solution.